Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 24.04
I use ASUS Vivobook 16'
I have Ubuntu noble, with all packages upgraded.
nicolas@localhost:~$ uname -a
Linux localhost 6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 21:49:14 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My bluetooth is not working :(
When I go to Settings, it displays "Bluetooth turned off".
It works on Windows.
The bluetooth module is loaded :
nicolas@localhost:~$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth            1032192  15 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb



nicolas@localhost:~$ rfkill list
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

BUT, the device seems down
nicolas@localhost:~$ hciconfig
    hci0: Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:12 acl:0 sco:0 commands:4 errors:0

I can't init the device :
nicolas@localhost:~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

nicolas@localhost:~$ sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    4.170666] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.170701] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.170705] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.170708] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.170712] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.807860] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.807874] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.807891] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.273886] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[   74.031405] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  215.280797] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[ 1326.317035] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[ 1699.627083] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110

I have restarted many times (because I read somewhere it can fix the issue), but it is the same.
nicolas@localhost:~$ lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb
0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5520]
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port [8086:a74d]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:17d1 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AC51 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Mediatek MT7610U]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 322e:2012 BillionPixels USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3579 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:ac22 Seagate RSS LLC BUP Slim

Any ideas?
Thanks

Please edit to include results from terminal for lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb

I did the edit Thanks

By the way, the network controller was not recognized during the install, I had to buy a USB wifi adapter.

The Bluetooth isn't supported on that wifi either, they don't have the firmware

you mean the driver?

No driver or firmware that I know of

I'm having the exact same problem and my bluetooth/network is a MediaTech chip as well. I'm doing this on Elementary OS, but it did work when I installed Xubuntu. Did you ever figure this out?
$ sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    2.977469] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.977492] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.977495] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.977498] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.977502] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.695009] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.695013] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.695017] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.579432] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  157.318761] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  387.525259] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
$ lspci -nnk|grep -iA3 net; lsusb
56:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7922]
    Subsystem: AzureWave MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:5911]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
57:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I226-V [8086:125c] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I226-V [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: igc
    Kernel modules: igc
58:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8520] (rev 01)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0c45:5011 Microdia USB Wired Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3585 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


@Rishon_JR, I didn't ask the original question so I'm not sure if you are asking me that question or the original poster.

My bad, thought this was a question.
